# Cordova Local Storage Sync with Server

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, cordova

I have a hybrid app where I use a backend server on the cloud using mongodb and nodejs. I feed my frontend web app and android app using http post and get request.

I was wondering if there is a best way to save the data (from server to android or vise versa) and sync them together. Much like how Trello does their android app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know local Storage is not a safe storage, as it can be cleaned as needed by the phone.
I recommend using sqlite for the mobile side.

for quick communication with server, i recommend using sockets  (i used it for my chat app)